# Built in slot for capturing number like first, second or fifth

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on a skill, which asks the user for selection of an item from a particular list. Now user's most intuitive response will be to say something like first or second. But built in slots AMAZON.Number only does not capture input like first or second. Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible with some other hack?

Answer (score 1):

Akshay,
AMAZON.Number is really only for numbers, where first, second and such are strings.

To do this, in the Developer console you would need to create a custom slot type called something like "positionChioces".  Then enter in first, second, third, fourth, etc.  Then add that slot type to your intent naming it choices, then picking "positionChioces".

This is from the JSON editor:

```
    "types": [
        {
            "name": "positionChioces",
            "values": [
                {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "fourth"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "third"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "second"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "first"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

From that point it would all depend on your code.  You can pull that slot from your user then use some logic saying if response was first, it will be the fist item in your array and so on.  Hope this helps.

D

Comment: That's very limiting. For instance user can say 'first one', or just plain 'one'. And we can't combine slots here (e.g AMAZON.Number and and custom slot).

Comment: @AkshayMilmile You can avoid any limitation on the defaults slots either by extending them or by defining your own custom slots